# Show Contact list on table view of iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I have a view controller where I have an add contact button and a table view. On clicking the add contact button a new view controller opens where there are a few textfields and labels and a button(Submit) which adds the textfield data to the database. I want that as I press the Submit button, the table view in the previous controller should contain the name and contact no. of the contact that was submitted. The addContact method is as follws:

```
-(IBAction)addContact{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [mDatabasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mDiary) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CONTACTS VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", mName.text, mContactno.text,mCemail.text,mClatitude.text,mClongitude.text];
        const char *insert_stmt1 = [insertSQL1 UTF8String];  
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(mDiary, insert_stmt1,

                           -1, &statement, NULL);

        NSString *tempName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mName.text];
        NSString *tempNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mContactno.text];
        tempName = [tempName stringByAppendingString:tempNo];

        [phoneContacts addObject:tempName];
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        [tableView reloadData];
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {  mStatus.text=@"Contact added";
            mName.text=@"";
            mContactno.text=@"";

            mCemail.text=@"";

            mClatitude.text=@"";
            mClongitude.text=@"";
        }   
        else {
            mStatus.text = @"Failed to add contact";
        }  
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(mDiary);
    }
}
```

The table view methods are:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.phoneContacts count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.phoneContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;


}
```

Nothing is getting shown in the table view. Why?

I've added a method populateContactTable:

```
-(IBAction)populateContactTable:(id)sender
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [mDatabasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath,&mDiary)== SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM CONTACTS"];
        const char *query_stmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(mDiary,
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                tempContactName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                tempContactNo = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)];

                tempContactName = [tempContactName stringByAppendingString:@"     "];
                tempContactName = [tempContactName stringByAppendingString:tempContactNo];

                [phoneContacts addObject:tempContactName];

                tableView.delegate = self;
                tableView.dataSource = self;
                [tableView reloadData];

                //  NSLog(@"%@",userName);
              //  return tempContactName;
            }

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(mDiary);
}
```

this method is called via a button in the root view controller. Still no data from the database is getting shown on the table.

Here's a snap of the storyboard:
[image: storyboard]

Comment: you must alloc your array phoneContacts. check it.

Comment: Ignore him.  This guy repeats similar questions, never showing the simplest form of appreciation.

Comment: @TBlue I'm sorry if u feel this way... I do show appreciation when my problem gets solved.. I'm stuck in a project whose requirements are ambiguous, hence the similiar kind of questions. I've initialized phoneContacts in viewDidLoad

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

Read Apples Documentation above, then, I suppose you know how to work with TableViews the rest shouln't be a problem.

Comment: @A-Live I have less than 15 rep, so I can't upvote.. :( I should probably show the storyboard here..

Comment: @Crazed'n'Dazed here you go, storyboard doesn't show us if your datasource is empty or filled correctly.